# How can I remove the underline of a linked image in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css

My table headers contain links that, when clicked, make an AJAX call to change the sort order.

```
<tr><th><a href="Name" style="display:block;">Name</a></th></tr>
```

This is great, I can click anywhere within the table header to activate the link.

Now I want to add sort arrows to indicate the sort order.

```
<tr><th><a href="Name" style="display:block;">Name<img src="arrow.png" /></a></th></tr>
```

This looks good in IE8:

[image]

However in FireFox and Chrome the image also has the underline:

[image]

I've been playing around with different css properties and I can't get it to work how I want. How can I get this to work in Firefox and Chrome like how it does in IE8?

Note that I want to have the whole cell to be clickable, so I need to use "display:block;" for the link and I also need the link text and image next to each other, so using "display:block;" on the image is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
a{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover span{text-decoration:underline;}
<tr>
    <th>
        <a href="Name" style="display:block;">
            <span>Name</span>
            <img src="arrow.png" />
        </a>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the underline on the "a", however I only want the text in the span to be underlined on hover, just like a normal link. When I try "a span:hover { text-decoration:underline; }" it doesn't work.

Comment: I'd seriously suggest spending some time brushing up on the basics of CSS, it's got a steepish learning curve, but you'll find it invaluable if you do this stuff much.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring I might be quicker, but I think you're being more useful :-)

Comment: maybe. I read in the SO Blog that Jeff wants this site to be a solid repository of quality answers.  So whenever I can, I try to make a habit of adding code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image needs to be inside the A tag, wrap the text in a span, then using css remove the underline from the A and place it on the SPAN.

Comment: How can i place it on the span? Setting text-decoration:none on "th a" and then text-decoration:underline on "th a span:hover" still makes the image underlined even though it is outside the span.

Comment: See rockinthesixstring's answer which is saying the same as my answer, but (s)he was nice enough to give you code.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="decoration:none;"
```

on the link will take away the underline.... if you want the image to be a part of the link surround it with a 2nd link that does the same thing and give it that style.

Comment: two matching anchor tags is not ideal. It can cause issues with SEO, and adds unnecessary code.

Answer (score -1):

or `a img{text-decoration:none;border:none;}`

Comment: do you test before answering?