# Remove line under image in link

Tags: html, css

I have a few instances where I place image within a link. Normally if you set border="0" there line under a link does not apply to the image. However, I had to specify DOCTYPE to be  and now in FF I see the line under all images.

I still would like to have my links underlined, but not the images within.

```
<a href="link.php"><img src="img.png" height="16" width="16" border="0"> link</a>
```

I've tried to solve it with CSS by adding

```
a img {
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work. I also tried:

```
a img {
    border:0
}
```

IE does not "underline" my images within a link... Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[Example Link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/UtKYn/6/)

[image]

I still would like to have my links underlined, but not the images within.

Comment: What do you mean by a line?  please include the snippet of html source code

Comment: Do you want the text of the link underlined, but the image not underlined? If so, Jeroen has the answer. If you want no underline, vinhboy has the answer.

Comment: I think this is FF specific bug. It is not suppose to happen in HTML and does not happen in IE, SAFARI and OPERA.

Comment: In the words of Homer Simpson: "If something is hard to do it's not worth doing."

Comment: I think I get the problem now from your example.  There is a 2-3px underline just to the left of the word link. Basically the empty space between the img and the word link is being underlined.

Comment: @Santa, this is not a bug. This is the way it is supposed to be. `a` is being underlined, not `img`

Comment: @Jason I get that. Also if I remove border="0" from image tag it will create a blue border around it. However, for a nearly 2 decades this was not a case in HTML -- why change it now?

Comment: @DougChamberlain it's not just the empty space -- it's the entire content within a link.

Comment: @santa my bad I had accidentally switched to ie8 when I tested this in jsfiddle.  BTW whoever figures this out will be santa's little helper!  ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the underline of a linked image in Firefox and Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168657/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-a-linked-image-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone cares, here's an alternative solution that I came up with to circumvent the issue:

```css
.nl {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="link.php" class="nl"><img src="img.png" height="16" width="16" border="0"><u>link</u></a>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to have a special case for links with images, give the `a` element a class and remove the text-decoration for that class:

HTML:

```
<a href="link.php" class="image-link"><img height="16" width="16" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
a img
{
  border: 0 none;
}
.image-link
{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is great if you *only* have an image within the link, however you have **both** text *and* images within the anchor.

The solution for that would be to add a `span` around the text within the anchor:

```
<a href="link.php" class="image-link"><img height="16" width="16" /> <span>link text here</span></a>
```

and add an additional style in the stylesheet:

```
.image-link span
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: I hate to say this but I think FF screwed this up and needs to fix it.

Comment: +1 This is also a good suggestion which doesn't deserve the down vote. The OP is constrained by "I have a lot of cases throughout my website. I am not able to go through all case and replace those" - he would prefer not to change HTML.

Comment: The more modern solution will be to use [`text-decoration-skip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip).

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to use the image as a background image instead of in the html, possibly the background of the parent element of the `a`.

Comment: Why is this down voted? It's a valid solution to what I suspect to be the correct interpretation of the question.

Comment: I have a lot of cases throughout my website. I am not able to go through all case and replace those. Alternatively i could probably use sprites.

Comment: @santa: So your actual question is this? "How can I get rid of the underline of *just* the image part (while keeping the text underlined) without changing from my posted HTML code. In all browsers preferably, but especially Firefox". You should edit your question to include wording similar to mine.

Comment: -1 moving semantic content (in this case an image) to a style is not a good suggestion.

Comment: @santa I´m not sure I understand you comment, you can´t replace them all but you **can** use sprites? Using sprites is basically what I am suggesting...

Comment: @zzzzBov 16 x 16 looks like some kind of a bullet to me but either way, we don´t know if it is or isn´t semantic content...

Comment: @jeroen You're right. What I was trying to say is that I am not able to go and replace ALL instances. I need to find a fix to FF problem. I may have to look into a FF style, which is not something I'd like either.

Comment: @jeroen, an image in HTML is semantic content, an image in a stylesheet is a style. The very fact that he's using an `img` tag *implies* that it's semantic content. you shouldn't change your content to change your style.

Comment: @zzzzBov: When the OP is saying things like "However, I had to specify DOCTYPE", you know he's not thinking about semantics.

Comment: @santa: You do have that in your post, but it's hard to understand, as evidenced by the multitude of people who didn't understand it.

Comment: @thirtydot now it's on top and bottom! :)

Comment: This is a very valid and useful solution. I recommend using this **especially** if you have multiple instances of multiple small images. It reduces server requests. @zzzzBov if the OP is using it as shown in the image, I don't believe it is semantic content. It is supplementary content.

Comment: I think I rather take a lead from Facebook and abandon underlining all together and just change the link color.

Comment: @santa That sounds like a very practical solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
a { text-decoration: none }
```

The underline is from the A-tag not the IMG

Comment: That would also remove the underline from the text.

Answer (score 1):

For those cases where editing the markup isn't an option (inaccessibility to templates and/or surrounding issues), you can use a little jQuery. You may need to adjust the syntax to override your CSS:

`jQuery('a > img').parent().css({'text-decoration' : 'none'});`

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
<a href="link.php" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="img.png" height="16" width="16" border="0"> link</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It may help if you explain your answer some. What was the problem with the OP's code? How does this fix it?

Comment: This way solved the problem for me, adding 

`style="text-decoration: none"`

to the link tag. It also should work editing CSS files like other explained in other questions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are linking to an image, try the following:

```
a[href$=jpg], a[href$=png] {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You can clearly see from the authors code snippet and title of the question he is not.

Answer (score -1):

My two cents:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var images = $(this).find("img");
    images.parent().addClass('no_border_img');
});
```

Loop all links and find images inside, then for each one add CSS style to the link.

Only for a image with link inside a previous link style. Remember to create the style for 'no_border_image'.