# hovering over one link makes tiny dash appear to right of it

Tags: hyperlink, hover

In this case, hovering over the left link makes a tiny dash appear to its right (between the two links).  How can I get rid of this? I see this in Safari and Chrome both, but I don't see anything in the style sheet that would make it do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Walls</title>
         <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="custo.css">

        <script src="prettyPhoto_compressed_3/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prettyPhoto_compressed_3/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="prettyPhoto_compressed_3/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

 </head>
 <body>

 <br>
                 <a href="gallery.html">
                 <img src="test.jpg" class="testclass" alt="test" width="170" />
                 </a>

                 <a href="info.html">
                 <img src="test.jpg" class="testclass" alt="test" width="55"  />
                 </a>



 <div class="container-fluid">
 <br>


 </div><!-- .container -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> <!--initialize prettyPhoto-->
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
      });
    </script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're seeing the same thing I'm seeing (I don't have all the style sheets), you're seeing the underline of the `a` tag for the image.

You can just remove that using `text-decoration: none` on your image links;

```
<a href="gallery.html" style="text-decoration: none !important;">
```

The `!important` at the end of the style helps to override any selectors in your css which may have already have an `!important` emphasis.

Of course this is in practice better done using a [class that you set on your image links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785601/477878).

Comment: i did this and also set my own class for it, and it keeps doing it. also what doesn't make sense is why the second link doesn't create a dash anywhere? i could post an image but i'm 1 rep short to be able to post images here.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, but I would like to contribute to something. This will help other people why the dash (-) appears.

This is because there is an empty space inside the a tag. For example:

```
<a href="#">
  <i>test</i>
</a>
```

If you set your line like this: `<a href="#"><i>test</i></a>` the dash/underline will disappear, but some tools might still format your code and they will add the space. So, using the css mentioned in the previous post will eliminate the issue.