# Remove line under navigation text

Tags: html, css, navigation, underline

**TLDR:** Please help me remove the underline of the text in the navigation.

**Context:**

*I am making a **Mobile** news application.*

**Problem:**

*I want to remove underlines on the text of the navigation.(Home, login)*

```
<h1>ignore this code  </h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uatmt99g/

Look specifically at the nav div and everything inside.

Similar post I have found whilst researching the issue (click link):

[Remove line under image in link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785422/remove-line-under-image-in-link)

I have tried the following but may have not implemented it correctly:

using CSS to remove text decoration,

using CSS to remove styling of text,

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the code to reproduce your problem in the question itself; don't post irrelevant code, with a request to ignore that code, to route around the checks. Relying on an external site renders your question pointless in the event that link gets removed, deleted, reorganised or that site simply falls over. See the guidelines for "[mcve]" and "[ask]" for our expectations and requirements of questions, and how asking a good question that meets those expectations gets you better answers.

Comment: Had problems making the code easy to read as for some reason it was missing Div tags out of the code boxes. I only signed up today and this is the first question I have ever asked on this site... I will look to improve my questions in the future. Sorry for offending anyone as it is already -1 votes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using link (`<a href = ""></a>`) tags. to remove those "underlines" simply use the css below

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Great, you have sorted my issue.Best part about it is that I have learned something new :) Thank you very much!

Comment: always welcome. also please mark one of us as an answer to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

The text with the underlines are links, so they have basic styling that goes with a link, including a line under the text. In order to remove it, you must specify `text-decoration: none;` to your `a`.

https://jsfiddle.net/uatmt99g/1/

Comment: Great, you have sorted my issue.Best part about it is that I have learned something new :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this after nav in the CSS.

nav a{text-decoration: none;}

Links acquire their own properties . you must declare with the #mynewpattern a{} format